# How to turn off this Intellij setting?

Tags: intellij-idea

This is my first post here. Looking for some help.

I was investigating Intellij settings and changed something I don't remember, which resulted in having constant code completion/suggestion after my cursor.

Does anyone know which is the name of this feature so I can turn it off again? I think this is not a default one becouse it's first time I see. For me at the moment is annoying.

Thanks in advance!

[(The red line is where my cursor is. The text to the right is the generated by the "feature")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeFNU.png)

I tryed looking for completion / suggestion at settings but this thing persists

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#basic_completion

Comment: It's hard to say, maybe you bound code completion on Settings | Keymap ? But you may use the menu **File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...** to reset the IDE.